# Dependency problem with gnu make

Tags: dependencies, makefile, gnu

I am facing a rather strange problem with make.
My make file contains:

```
all: item1 item2

item1: dep1 dep2
dep1:
    @echo
    cd $(HOME)/apps; /bin/rm -f $(D_ALL_OBJECTS) 
    cd $(SRCHOME)/fusionapps; make -k -f $(SOMEMAKEFILE) $(D_ALL_OBJECTS)
    @echo
dep2:
    @echo
    cd $(HOME)/apps; /bin/rm -f $(D2_ALL_OBJECTS) 
    cd $(SRCHOME)/fusionapps; make -k -f $(SOMEMAKEFILE) $(D2_ALL_OBJECTS)
    @echo
item2: ...
.....
```

Now, "`make -f Makefile item1`" works, but when I try "`make -f Makefile all`" it doesn't work. Do you people see any problems in my makefile?

Thanks

---

*Addendum*:

Well, it looks like make doesn't allow targets that have same name as some directory in the current level. Observation:

- "all" is a directory @ $(HOME)/apps
- `all1: item1 item2` works
- `all: item1 item2` doesn't work

So any target name having same name as a directory seems to fail (as in, fails to do anything useful).

I am pretty sure I am doing something absurdly wrong here.

Comment: make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

Comment: Fails to do anything useful - sort of.  The directory exists; if it was last modified (a file added or removed) since the dependencies were last changed, there is nothing that make needs to do to bring it up to date.  It is good advice not to use a directory name as a target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write:

```
all: item1 item2
```

and then request `make all`, that tells `make`:

- Find a file system object called `all` and make sure anything it depends on (`item1`, `item2`) is up to date.
- If `all` does not exist or is out of date w.r.t either of the file system objects called `item1` or `item2`, then do the specified actions (none in this example) and then consider `all` up to date.
- If `all` is a directory, it exists.  If it has been modified recently, it will be up to date.

The suggestion to use `.PHONY: all item1 item2` is good for GNU Make; it does not work with other variants of `make`.

Do not use target names that are directory names - unless you're sure you know what you're doing.  And use `.PHONY`.

Answer (score 1):

Try [phony-declaring](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) your all-target.

Answer (score 0):

Well looks like make doesn't allow targets who have same name as some directory in the current level.
Observation :

-"all" is a directory @ $(HOME)/apps
-all1/2/3: item1 item2 works
-all: item1 item2 doesn't work so is the any target name having same name as the directory.

I am pretty sure I am doing anything absurdly wrong here.

Comment: Please add extra info to the question.  I've done it for you; now remove this.  Thanks.